# Align two same sized boxes with differing origin points

Tags: math, geometry

I have two boxes, both are the exact same size and shape. Box A's origin is in the very centre of the shape whereas box B's origin is in an arbitrary place within the shape. We also have the min and max points of each box (relative to the origin) so that we are able to determine where the origin is within the box. The goal is to use box A's origin position to offset box B's origin position so that all of the faces of both boxes align.

I'm sure this is a simple math problem but I just can't quite figure it out how to use box B's min and max points to offset box B's origin so that the boxes align.

```
boxA        = BoxShape()
boxA.min    = [-5, -7, -3]
boxA.max    = [ 5,  7,  3]
boxA.origin = [10, 78, 43]

boxB        = BoxShape()
boxB.min    = [-4, -4, -4]
boxB.max    = [ 6, 10,  2]
boxB.origin = boxA.origin + some_offset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more poking around I finally found the solution. The problem I was having was that I was using box B's min instead of max in the equation I wrote. Switching it out for max now works.

```
function get_offset(min, max, half)
    min  = math.abs(min)
    max  = math.abs(max)
    half = math.abs(half)

    if max > half then
        return half - max
    else
        return min - half
    end
end

function process(entity)
    min      = entity.scale * entity.min
    max      = entity.scale * entity.max
    size     = entity.shape:getSize()
    position = entity.rigidBody:getPosition()

    x = get_offset(min.x, max.x, size.x / 2)
    y = get_offset(min.y, max.y, size.y / 2)
    z = get_offset(min.z, max.z, size.z / 2)

    entity.position.x = position.x + x
    entity.position.y = position.y + y
    entity.position.z = position.z + z
end
```